# MongoDB aggregation - ignore key names

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a query:

```
db.events.aggregate(
  { $match: { "camera._id": "1NJE48", "start_timestamp": { $lte: 1407803834.07 } } },
  { $sort: { "start_timestamp": -1 } },
  { $limit: 2 },
  { $project: { "_id": 0, "snapshots": 1 } }
)
```

It returns data like so:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "snapshots" : {
                "1401330834010" : {
                    "uploaded_timestamp" : 1401330895,
                    "filename_timestamp" : 1401330834.01,
                    "timestamp" : 1401330834.01

                },
                "1401330835010" : {
                    "uploaded_timestamp" : 1401330896,
                    "filename_timestamp" : 1401330835.01,
                    "timestamp" : 1401330835.01
                },
                "1401330837010" : {
                    "uploaded_timestamp" : 1401330899,
                    "filename_timestamp" : 1401330837.01,
                    "timestamp" : 1401330837.01
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "snapshots" : {
                "1401319837010" : {
                    "uploaded_timestamp" : 1401319848,
                    "filename_timestamp" : 1401319837.01,
                    "timestamp" : 1401319837.01
                },
                "1401319838010" : {
                    "uploaded_timestamp" : 1401319849,
                    "filename_timestamp" : 1401319838.01,
                    "timestamp" : 1401319838.01
                },
                "1401319839010" : {
                    "uploaded_timestamp" : 1401319850,
                    "filename_timestamp" : 1401319839.01,
                    "timestamp" : 1401319839.01
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I would like an array of snapshots:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "uploaded_timestamp" : 1401330895,
            "filename_timestamp" : 1401330834.01,
            "timestamp" : 1401330834.01

        },
        {
            "uploaded_timestamp" : 1401330896,
            "filename_timestamp" : 1401330835.01,
            "timestamp" : 1401330835.01
        },
        {
            "uploaded_timestamp" : 1401330899,
            "filename_timestamp" : 1401330837.01,
            "timestamp" : 1401330837.01
        },
        {
            "uploaded_timestamp" : 1401319848,
            "filename_timestamp" : 1401319837.01,
            "timestamp" : 1401319837.01
        },
        {
            "uploaded_timestamp" : 1401319849,
            "filename_timestamp" : 1401319838.01,
            "timestamp" : 1401319838.01
        },
        {
            "uploaded_timestamp" : 1401319850,
            "filename_timestamp" : 1401319839.01,
            "timestamp" : 1401319839.01
        }

    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I.e. no key names. I'm struggling to understand how to deal with the aggregation framework when the key names are unique like they are here.

Comment: You'll have to parse out the ```"uploaded_timestamp", "filename_timestamp", "timestamp"``` fields with some JavaScript. I don't think the aggregation pipeline can deal with unique ObjectID's like that...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the only way you know the key names is by looking at the document itself. MongoDB does not handle this type of situation well, in general. You are expected to know the structure of your own documents, i.e. to know what the keys are and what their types should be.

I don't know your use case and there's no sample document so I can't evaluate your data model, but having keys-as-values is generally a bad idea as you will run into a host of limitations whenever you can't say what the keys on a document should be a priori. Consider using an array instead of an embedded object for snapshots, or using an array of key-value pairs pattern like

```
{
    ...
    "result" : [ 
    {
        "snapshots" : [
            { 
                "key" : "1401330834010", 
                "value" : {
                    "uploaded_timestamp" : 1401330895,
                    "filename_timestamp" : 1401330834.01,
                    "timestamp" : 1401330834.01
                },
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
}
```

If you provide a sample document and some detail about what you're trying to accomplish I'd be happy to provide more complete advice.

Comment: Thanks. Changing the schema is a largish task, but something we've added to our list.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a stop gap solution. We will store an array of the snapshot keys, in an array on an event. It essentially acts as an index. We can then perform 2 queries - one to fetch the keys, and do a filter, and another to correctly fetch the single snapshot we need.

It's no pretty, nor backwards compatible, but it will hopefully speed it up.